# Find which sentence the user clicks on in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want to make a text reader app. I have a paragraph and I want to play the audio that corresponds to the sentece that the user click on. How can I find out which sentence the user clicks on?

```java
    private void init() {
        String definition = "Oh My God What Are You Doing Here My Extremely Nice Friend Who Lives In Timbuktu".trim();
        TextView definitionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        definitionView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        definitionView.setText(definition, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        Spannable spans = (Spannable) definitionView.getText();
        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.US);
        iterator.setText(definition);
        int start = iterator.first();
        for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator
                .next()) {
            String possibleWord = definition.substring(start, end);
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0))) {
                ClickableSpan clickSpan = getClickableSpan(possibleWord);
                spans.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private ClickableSpan getClickableSpan(final String word) {
        return new ClickableSpan() {
            final String mWord;
            {
                mWord = word;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Log.d("tapped on:", mWord);
                Toast.makeText(widget.getContext(), mWord, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
            }
        };
    }
```

This is what I have so far, but it only checks for words not sentences.

Comment: On what are you displaying your text?

Comment: @blackapps In a TextView